# How to rollback transaction invoked with jpa entity listeners

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, audit, entitylisteners

I'm using jpa , spring data and entity listeners to audit my entities precisely on postUpdate , postPersist , PostRemove

This is a pseudo code of my entity listener class

```
public class EntityListener extends AuditingEntityListener {

@PostUpdate
public void postPersist(Object auditedEntity) {
    writer.saveEntity(auditedEntity,"UPDATE");
}
```

This the pseudo code of the Writer class

```
public class Writer {

@Async
public void saveEntity(Object auditedEntity, String action) {
    try {

//some code to prepare the history entity

        historyDAO.save(entity);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

when an exception is thrown in Writer class , the auditedEntity is updated or inserted however the historyEntity where i store the audit action doesnt

The problem is i need  to invoke the saveEntity method in another thread for performance issue (@Async) but in that case a new transaction is open instead of the previously one which opened

how can i solve the rollack issue for both transactions
so when an exception is throwen both historyEntity and auditedEntity not persisted

Comment: Could you please explain the use case a little deeper? The expected result would seem to be that one thread executes the 'parent' transaction and returns control to the caller, but at the same time, the state of that transaction is undetermined (the 'child' transaction may still rollback changes made in the 'parent' transaction). That implies that the calling thread does not care about the outcome of the operation. How is that any different from executing *the entire transaction* on a separate thread?

Comment: (the 'child' transaction may still rollback changes made in the 'parent' transaction
=> No , the parent transaction and the child transaction are independent

Comment: 'when an exception is throwen both historyEntity and auditedEntity not persisted' sounds like the opposite of independent

Comment: sorry may be you missunterstand my request , this is what i ask for : when an exception is throwen , i want rollback everything
my application now only rollback the child transaction

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to rollback *both* the child *and* the parent transaction when an exception is thrown from within `Writer.saveEntity`. What I'm asking is *why* you feel you need it in the first place (I can't see how performance can be gained in this scenario by separating the logic onto multiple threads). Hibernate transactions cannot be shared across multiple threads, so there is really no easy solution

Comment: because class Writer contains complicated methods with many loops and if-statement and it will be invoked on every call of DAO class to track modifications on entities that's why i want to use it in seprate thread

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to rollback *both* the child *and* the parent transaction when an exception is thrown from within `Writer.saveEntity`.

The problem is that the thread with the original transaction would still need to wait for all these complicated operations to finish before it could mark the transaction as committed. You can't easily span a transaction across multiple threads, either.

The only thing you *could probably* do to speed things up is you could run the logic of generating the history entities in parallel, and then save them all just before the transaction commits.

One way of doing that that I can think of is using a Hibernate interceptor:

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    private List<Callable<BaseEntity>> historyEntries;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    ...

    public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        List<Future<BaseEntity>> futures = executor.invokeAll(historyEntries);
        if (executor.awaitTermination(/* some timeout here */)) {
            futures.stream().map(Future::get).forEach(entity -> session.save(object));
        } else {
            /* rollback */
        }
    }
}
```

Your listener code then becomes:

```
@PostUpdate
public void postPersist(Object auditedEntity) {
    interceptor.getHistoryEntries().add(new Callable<BaseEntity> {
        /* history entry generation logic goes here */
    });
}
```

(note that the above code is greatly simplified, you could use any other asynchronous execution API, the basic idea is that you need to block in `AuditInterceptor.beforeTransactionCompletion`, waiting for all the history entries to be generated)

However, I would strongly advise against using the above technique, as it is rather complicated and error prone.

If you look here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/events/Events.html, you'll find that Hibernate interceptors have more interesting methods that could help you gather auditing info, and that perhaps your implementation could make use of them, possibly avoiding the need for complicated logic altogether (Hibernate already does track changes to fields of individual entities, so you get that information for free).

Why reinvent the wheel, though? If you dig even deeper, you'll find the Hibernate Envers module (http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/, works for both JPA and pure Hibernate) which gives you business auditing out of the box. Envers already digs into the above mechanism, so hopefully the performance issue would go away.

Final note: have you measured how long history entry generation takes? I would guess that executing `for` loops and `if` statements might be cheaper than database access operations. If I were you, **I wouldn't do any of the above unless I was absolutely sure that's where the performance bottleneck was**.